Is this proof correct for Putnam 1986 B4?
I have been practicing on some old Putnam questions, and I attempted to solve this 1986 Putnam B4:

For a positive real number $r$ define $G(r)$ to be the minimum value of $|r-\sqrt{m^2+n^2}|$ for all positive integers $m,n$.
Show that the limit $ \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} G(r)$ exists and is equal to $0$.

My proof is a little non rigorous, and is basically based on the fact that the "lattice points" defined by $m$ and $n$ get arbitrarily close to any real number.
Let's say $r$ is a real number, and $A \leqslant r < A+1$ for a positive integer $A$. If we start from the combination $m = A$ and $n = 0$, the number of real numbers in the interval $[A,A+1]$ that are representable in the square root form shown above are all the combinations starting from that combination up until a combination that is larger than $A+1$. This can be shown to be when $m=A$ and $n > \sqrt{A+\frac{1}{2}}-1$. This shows that the number of real numbers in that interval that can be expressed using that square root form are on the order of $\sqrt{A}$. As the upper limit tends to infinity, the number of real numbers in this interval grows as the square root of the upper limit and this tends to infinity, thus showing any real number will be representable in this form as $r$ tends to infinity.
My question is if this proof is valid, as the proof I read on the official solution list is based on showing that the distance between $r$ and the closest lattice points is inversely proportional to the square root of the upper limit, and thus tends to $0$ as $r$ tends to infinity. I am not sure if my proof is actually rigorous or just a good idea that may or may not work.
I also had another proof idea based on rather showing that since $0 \leqslant G(r) < 1$ for all $r$, if I could show that $G(r)$ was monotonically decreasing, then I could show it had to converge by the Bounded convergence theorem.
If anyone could correct my proof it would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Given $\epsilon$, you can find $N$,  such that $r<\sqrt{4N+3}<r+\epsilon$ for big $r$.

Your Proof 1 is a good idea , though it is incomplete & not right.
You are considering $m=A$ & increasing $n$ , hence you are not checking all Pairs $(m,n)$
There are Cases where the minimal value occurs at $m \approx A/\sqrt{2} \approx n$ , though those Cases do no occur in your scanning.
We can check that $m \approx A/\sqrt{2} \approx n$ gives $G(r) \approx 0$ when $r \approx A$
Your Proof 1 assumes that minimal value occurs elsewhere which is wrong.
More work is required to rectify this gap.
Eventually , it will essentially work out to the Original Solution , though worded with little changes here & there.
Your Proof 2 is not a good idea , because it is wrong & unrectifiable.
We can check that $G(r)$ is not "monotone Decreasing" : It is $0$ when-ever $\sqrt{m^2+n^2}=r$ & then it "Increases" immediately & then later "Decreases" : It is always oscillating & wavering.
